# Renew puppet CA with puppetlabs/certregen

Tags: certificate, puppet, renewal

I'm trying to renew a Puppet CA certificate and propagate it to the agents according to this https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-certregen manual. While the first step of regenerating the CA certificate was easy to do, distributing the new CA to the clients does not work.

I created a file in the `/manifests` folder of the puppet repository called `ca.pp` with the content `include certregen::client`, but after a `puppet update` on the server and `puppet agent -t -v` on one of the clients nothing changes. I still get the warning `Warning: Certificate 'Puppet CA: puppetmaster.domain.name' will expire on 2019-10-20T10:35:43UTC`.

Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge about puppet since I inherited the setup from a former colleague who isn't available any more. So I don't even know where to start to debug this issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is with Puppet CA on the Master, not on the agents, and I don't think you have to re-distribute the CA. The only thing you need is to renew the Puppet CA (read this: https://blog.flyingcircus.io/2017/09/01/how-to-renew-puppet-ca-and-server-certificates-in-place/). also try asking for help on https://puppetcommunity.slack.com, as you may get **live** support/help from the community.

Comment: Thank you for your input, unfortunately one has to have an `@puppet.com` or `@puppetlabs.com` e-mail address to access the Slack channel, which you can only get via an invite.

Comment: You don't need a `@puppet.com` or `@puppetlabs.com` e-mail. Try to register to slack with your own e-mal.

Answer (score 0):

The file named `ca.pp` containing the line `include certregen::client` has to be imported in the `sites.pp` file with `import 'ca.pp'` in the main `manifests` directory.

After that step, the CA certificate was successfully distributed among the clients.